# Laravel nginx.conf with official Heroku php buildpack?

Tags: laravel, heroku, nginx

I have the following in `nginx.conf in my project root

```
location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

But only in the `/` path works, all others are coming up with a 404 error.

How can I make Laravel work on heroku with nginx?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This ended up working for me:
Procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

nginx.conf

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to app.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too to get my [kwiki](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/kwiki) install working.

Comment: do you put the nginx.conf file in the root or in the public folder

Comment: @user3666882 It's been awhile but I'm fairly certain it had to be the root dir

Comment: Works great with Heroku and Laravel 5.5

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `fastcgi_*` directives; try this after your `location` directive:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

*Source: [How to Install Laravel with an Nginx Web Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)*

Comment: That is incorrect and will not work on Heroku, because there is no `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` socket - it's in a different location (and the default config gives named upstreams and named locations you can use instead so your local config is never tied to the exact location and thus won't break when it changes). Please don't blindly copy/paste answers from documentation to SO if it doesn't apply to the question. Heroku is not a plain Ubuntu 14.04 server.